# find second element of array through recursion Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have written the following code which returns the second element of the list.

```
first :: [Int] -> Int
first []= 0                                                                                                                                        
first [x] =x
first (x:x1:xs) = x1
```

It is working fine, but I want it to go through recursion, For Example, I keep on recursing the list as soon as it reaches the second number it gives our second number.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Okay, cool, you've told us what you want to do. What's stopping you from doing it that we can help with?

Comment: `listitem n ls = if n == 1 then head ls else listitem (n-1) (tail ls)` will produce any item from a list, like `listitem 2 [3,6,9,12]` yields 6

Comment: Create a function to get only the second item `get2nd = listitem 2` then `get2nd "abcdef"` yields `'b'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a « natural » case for recursion but you could write this if you absolutely want recursion...

```
first :: [Int] -> Int
first []= 0                                                                                                                                        
first [x] =x
first (x:x1:xs) = first [x1]
```

Comment: `first [] = first [0,0]; first [x] = first [x,x]; first [x,y] = y; first (x:y:z:xs) = first (x:y:xs)`

Comment: @JorgeAdriano Perhaps it goes without saying, but that would be pretty slow on a long list, as you need `n-2` recursive calls before you finally get to a list of size 2.

Comment: @chepner I know :) just kidding, I mean there's no point in making this recursive in the first place, so at least making it O(n) on list length feels more like "true recursion" than O(1). Doesn't work for infinite lists though.

Comment: bradm's answer is a perfectly fine recursive (ok, corecursive, but it could be made recursive) function.

Comment: @chepner: depends what you mean by "perfectly fine", as an exercice yes, but would you ever implement such a procedure recursively for a real case?
NB : at JorgeAdriano: yes that's a good one!

Comment: @godot No, but it does generalize to arbitrary `n` other than 2 with minimal effort.

Answer (score 3):

Good question! The typical way to do this through recursion is to use turn your function into a thin wrapper around a recursive function with an extra argument (typically called `go`):

```
first :: [Int] -> Int
first list = go 0 list
  where
    go        1 (x:_)  = x
    go curIndex (x:xs) = go (curIndex+1) xs
    go        _ []     = 0
```

However, Haskell uses currying, so the definition of `first` can be slightly simplified to `first = go 0`.

Another change I would recommend is to use the `Maybe` type from the Prelude:

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

That is, a value of type `Maybe Int` can be either a `Just` value containing an `Int`, or it can be a `Nothing` value containing no `Int`. Typically this type is used in situations where a computation can either succeed or fail - such as this function! So it can be changed now to the following:

```
first :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
first = go 0
  where
    go        1 (x:_)  = Just x     -- returning the second value
    go curIndex (x:xs) = go (curIndex+1) xs
    go        _ []     = Nothing    -- returning Nothing if it doesn't exist
```

And now we can change the type to make it more generic (and also shorten the name `curIndex` a bit) to give a final recursive answer. I've also changed the name to `second`, because that name reflects the function's purpose better (you're getting the *second* element, after all):

```
second :: [a] -> Maybe a
second = go 0
  where
    go 1 (x:_)  = Just x
    go i (x:xs) = go (i+1) xs
    go _ []     = Nothing
```

Comment: Those should have `go _ [] = Nothing`, not `go 2 [] = Nothing`; I think that makes the case analysis exhaustive.

Comment: Also, `go 1 (x:_) = Just x`.

Comment: @chepner Good point about the exhaustive case analysis - I'll edit it in. Also, as for `go 1 (x:_)`, usually I would do that, but the question specifically asked about recursion, so I thought I would do it in a recursive way - note that `i` increases until it reaches `2`, at which point it returns the current element.

Comment: But since you're starting at 0, by the time you get to `go 2`, you'll have already discarded two elements, and `x` will bind to the third. `go 0 "abc" == go 1 "bc" == go 2 "c" == "c"`.